# secret test menu (ie *#*#4636#*#*) has no battery, network locks, or phone tests

Tags: motorola-moto-g, motorola

just got a refurbished moto g4. I wanted to run some tests and check the battery health status, using the secret code, but there's only those 4 in there. How come?

In the mean time, I tried using apps to check battery health (not sure how accurate it was), and manually test other things (any tips?)

[image]

Comment: Not sure where you got the impression that this menu would contain such tests - AOSP implementations has only contained the items in the pic since the beginning (?).